# Issue while moving flutter app from ios to windows and vice versa

Tags: flutter

I have created flutter app on ios device, built and ran successfully on simulator.

I have taken that code to my windows machine. When I opened the project on visual studio code, I get following error.
[main.dart issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bd3XX.png)

after running flutter clean, I get this error(it seems that on ios machine the flutter path is different then on windows)
[flutter clean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXQ9P.png)

When I move app created in windows to ios, by changing the paths in .packages file, I was able to remove the error but the files and folders which I had added and referenced in main.dart file, the project was unable to locate that.Even the intellisense doesn't show my files.

Basically I want to know the way maintain my code which I can reuse on both environment.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You need to run `flutter packages get` when you move the code from one machine to another.

Actually you should delete all directories and files listed in `.gitignore`.
These files contain machine specific paths that likely don't match from one machine to another.

Using git to pass changes (clone/commit/pull) would do this automatically.

A related issue [Improve error output for projects copyied from another machine. #26014](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26014)